# Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory // invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

#### I am trying to reinstall *mysql-server* on my wsl *Ubuntu 18.04*.

*(I have MySQL server on Windows 10, but on port 3307. Idk if this matters but just in case!)*

I couldn't `sudo service mysql start` nor `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` and it returned

```
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//.cache’: Permission denied
-su: 19: /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: cannot create //.cache/wslu/integration: Directory nonexistent [Failed]
```

I googled about reinstalling mysql in Ubuntu and followed the following procedure.
 - https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1761

```
sudo su
apt-get remove --purge 'mysql*'
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
rm -f /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
apt-get install mysql-server
```

But while trying `apt-get install mysql-server` I got the error below.

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                         [ OK ]
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/5: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/10: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/6: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/5/fd/7: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/5/fd/10: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/5/fd/5: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/843/fd/7: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/843/fd/10: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/843/fd/5: Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.
```

I've been googling `Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory`  and `invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel` problems but could not find the right solution for this issue.

I really appreciate if you could give me some advice on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When I looked into the log file `/var/log/mysql/error.log` I found

```
[ERROR] [MY-012585] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
```

I disabled the use of Native AIO by creating a new config file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/no_native_aio.conf`:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
```

Then I was able to start the databse server like so:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

I also had to run

```
 sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

to set the password for the root user.

and I had to trick `dpkg` into believing that postinstall script had run
successfully by:

- adding `exit 0`  as the second line in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst`
- running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- removing the  `exit 0`  from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst`

Answer (score 1):

This will be a WSL1 vs WSL2 issue. The `/proc` directory isn't fully populated with WSL1. To check your version run (from powershell) `wsl -l -v`. If it doesn't give you any version info, then you're on WSL1.

Comment: I'm using WSL1 as you mentioned! Should I upgrade it to WSL2 then? Thank you!